# App crashes strangely regarding MKMapView memory issues

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, mkmapview, viewcontroller

I've been developing an app which was working perfectly fine until I added an MKMapView. If I navigate in the map for a broader area, dismiss the view controller with the map and add a new view controller, the app will crash with Xcode saying "Lost connection to iPhone".

I have searched online and I found it should be a memory issue. So I have used a lot of ways to clean the memory of MKMapView, including only storing one instance of the MKMapView in AppDelegate and cleaning it after ViewDidDisappear like this:

```
    if let annotations = self.mapView?.annotations {
        self.mapView?.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    }

    if self.mapView?.mapType == MKMapType.standard {
        self.mapView?.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
    } else if self.mapView?.mapType == MKMapType.hybrid {
        self.mapView?.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    }

    self.mapView?.delegate = nil
    self.mapView?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.mapView = nil
```

Even more strange is that when I was tracking the memory usage, while in the map, the memory usage can go up to 300+mb and it seems to clean itself while exploring more. However, there will be around 200mb left after I dismiss that view controller and when I'm adding another simple VC with just one UIIMageView, it crashes with the "Lost Connection" thing.

I'm new to memory management but I do have a screenshot here for instrument profile:

[image: instrument profile]

Just like here in the image. Generation A is the point where I presented the view controller with the MKMapView and Generation B is the point where I dismissed that view. The memory usage was apparently dropping, which is good. But as soon as I click on presenting a different view controller, it disconnects just like in Xcode.

I have done a lot of research on this and I really don't know what to do at this point. Thanks if you guys can help me out here!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem fixed after I switched to Google Map...

Comment: it may be true answer.